# EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs not found doing release build UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I can build my application in Visual Studio in debug mode, however when I try to build it in Release mode I get the Error: `EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs not found`, with message: `You need to find EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame` The message pops up in a new tab in Visual Studio, labeled "Source Not Found".

Under "Source search information:

> Locating source for '/*/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs'. (No checksum.)
> Looking in script documents for '/*/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs'...
> Looking in the projects for '/_/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs'.
> The file was not found in a project.
> ....
> The file was not found in a project.
>
> Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include'...Looking
> in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cvt'...
> Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\msclr'...
>
> The
> debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the
> debugger will not ask the user to find the file:
> /*/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs.
> The debugger could not locate the source file
> '/*/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs'.

Why would a change such as this happen from debug to release mode?

Comment: The Release mode enables optimizations((e.g. code inlining will be applied in many places)) and generates without any debug data. As a result, lots of code could be completely removed or rewritten in Release mode, which causes more errors occur in Release mode than in Debug mode. Release mode could run faster than debug mode due to the optimizations.

Comment: For more information about the differences between Release mode and Debug mode, you could refer to the [document](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/).

You could try to debug you UWP project in Release mode and uncheck the option **Optimize code** (**Properties > Build**). Or, you could check if the EffectDirectPropertyChangeDefinition.cs file exists in your project.